# import xml - how to refresh a Google Sheet automatically

Tags: javascript, xml

Hi i Have 4 google sheets using import xml (because of google 50 import limits) on each which are sorting and then feeding data from a webpage to another 'summary' sheet.  I just need a script for the 4 google sheets that refreshes the importxml every minute or so.

Either that, or to refresh the importxml  when the specified information on the target (source) web page changes.

also, as this would be used from a mobile device some of the time, would the 4 sheets have to be kept open ?

Comment: clearly in answer given below, amend cells as appropriate

Answer (score 1):

I eventually came across, sorry cant find the OP for it now - seems to do the trick ..

```
function getData() {
var queryString = Math.random();

var cellFunction1 = '=IMPORTXML("' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D1').getValue() + '?' + queryString + '","'+ SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E1').getValue() + '")';
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D2').setValue(cellFunction1);


}
```